# Android: KeyValuePairs to json

Tags: java, android, json

Is there some easy way of transforming KeyValuePairs into json

For Example

```
{ "keyvaluepairs" : 
         { "long": "6,5",
            "heavy": "200",
         }
```

}

long and heavy are inside the keyvaluepairs? some easyway of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what data structure you mean by KeyValuePairs, but presumably you can do something like:

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject("keyvaluepairs");
for (Entry entry : keyValuePairs) {
  object.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue();
}
```